# Dualboot-Ubuntu20.04lts

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

How to Dual boot with Ubuntu20.04lts 64bit installed on 256Gig SSD and Ubuntu 16.04lts 32 bit installed on 320 Gig SATA HDD.

I've currently got 20.04.3lts installed on the 256 Gig SSD and have a spare SATA 320 Gig HDD available. Am busy installing the Ubuntu 16.04lts 32 bit on the HDD and presume the setup will be detected by grub and offer dual boot select.. holding thumbs it works or need some guidance.

I need to run the 32 bit version OS to be able to run an older Microchip MPLAB X IDE version that can work with Assembly Language. Unfortunately recent updates have prevented me from using the solution I had running Oracle Virtual box with Windows 7 32 bit as virtual machine. All worked well till the updates and have been unable to compile programs since.

My thoughts are to try install the Ubuntu 16.04lts 32 bit on the SATA HDD and then boot to this HDD and hopefully be successful in installing the older MPLAB X IDE for 32 bit systems and compile Assembly programs again...

Comment: 16.04 is EOL pr. April 30th 2021 and therefor off-topic here.

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Comment: Apologies for mentioning a distribution no longer supported. The 20.04.4lts OS is in perfect working order but just not able to offer a solution to work with a 32 bit programming Assembly language MPASM for Microchip devices. Thankfully the installation of the 32 bit version of Ubuntu on the HDD and direct access to boot this HDD using the MSI motherboard BIOS resolved a rather unique solution I thought may be of interest and benefit to many others who need a practical solution to learn and work with a vitally important and in use language still today.

Comment: Ubuntu provided 32-bit ISOs into the *disco* cycle (ie. 19.04) whilst it too is EOL, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS is a *i386* release that is still on-topic on this site; so 32-bit x86 or *i386*, 32-bit *armhf* are still on-topic here; 16.04 however is EOL.

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about the 32 bit distro installation messing up the Ubuntu 20.04 installation:

1. Power down and disconnect the SSD
2. Run the installer for the 32 bit distro and shutdown.
3. Reconnect the SSD and boot it into Ubuntu 20.04
4. Update grub from Ubuntu 20.04
5. Reboot and you should be have distro choices.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks all worked out just right, the MSI motherboard BIOS allows F11 to gain direct access to boot the HDD with the "other" OS so I can program 32 bit devices which unfortunately does not work on the "current 64bit 20.04.3lts"